# Boolean algebra Simplify the expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Simplify the expression using the rules in Boolean algebra. 
**(a+b')(a'+b)(a+b)**

Here's a list of the rules I got. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDY5H.jpg)

My thinking is that the rule B18 is relevant here. But I can't get it to work.

Comment: I mean the rule B19

Comment: Use 14 several times as a possibility.

Comment: De Moivre (B21) and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You guess the rules:
$$(a+b')(a'+b)(a+b) = (aa'+ab+b' a' +b'b)(a+b)=(ab+b'a')(a+b)=$$$$=aba + abb + b'a'a + b'a'b = ab+ab = ab$$

Comment: Thanks I did not know that you could multiply like that in Boolean algebra.

Comment: @Daniel: Look carefully at B14 in your list to understand, for example, the first step.